# Comment shortcuts are not working for CMakeLists.txt files in Visual Studio 2022 (17.5.3)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Pretty much the title. I have recently installed Visual Studio 2022 Community on a new machine, with the option toggled for "Desktop development for C++". I have a project folder opened in Visual Studio, with a root-level `CMakePresets.json`

Toggle/untoggle comments for selected code is working just fine for `*.cpp` and `*.h` files. However, it seems that Visual Studio doesn't know how to leave comments in my `CMakeLists.txt`. It simply doesn't do anything. Has anybody run into this bug before? Strangely, it comments the `CMakePresets.json` just fine.

Comment: "_Strangely, it comments the CMakePresets.json just fine._" weird. Related: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22602

Comment: I face the same issue, and I have never seen an IDE that doesn't include the toggle block comment option in either the right-click context menu or the top navigation bar's dropdown menu.